# Artifacts (.jar) Generated using with Intellij Idea Scala Spark throws ClassNotFoundException with spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, classnotfoundexception

I have gone through various related suggestions, but I am still struggling.

What I have:

```
Spark:2.3.1
Scala:2.11.8
OS: Windows 10
IDE:Intellij Idea
Code:
     package: testpackage
                      merge.scala -->has do() method
                      mymain.scala -->has main() method and inside that merge.do()

Project Settings--Artifacts-->
                              Main Class-->testpackage.mymain
                              Class Path--><blank>
```

What is working:

```
1. Running properly on IDE
2. JAR creation : Artifacts are getting generated properly as testpackage.jar
3. I can see the classes(along with various other libraries) when I open testpackage.jar in winrar as:
   testpackage\merge$$anonfun$1.class
   testpackage\merge$$anonfun$2.class
   testpackage\merge$.class
   testpackage\merge.class
   testpackage\mymain$.class
   testpackage\mymain.class
```

What is not working

```
spark-submit from command prompt throws exception:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testpackage.mymain
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:238)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:851)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

More info:

```
1. spark-submit executed from jar folder (~out\artifacts\testpackage_jar)
2. the testpackage.jar is about 128MB
```

Same exception if I try:

```
spark-submit testpackage.jar C:\temp\input.csv
spark-submit --class testpackage.mymain testpackage.jar C:\temp\input.csv
spark-submit --class mymain testpackage.jar C:\temp\input.csv
```

Also tried with following statement in build.sbt

```
mainClass in (Compile, packageBin) := Some("testpackage.mymain")
```

Also tried with following statement in build.sbt

```
mainClass in (Compile, packageBin) := Some("mymain")
```

Also tried by keeping jar in Spark bin folder, in my machine it is

```
C:\Spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin
```

Tried with --mater local[*], and a few other combinations.

Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Just in case anyone else bump on this. Make sure that you have only 1 entry, which is "'your package' compile output" under "'your package.jar'" on Project Structure-->Artifacts-->Output Layout

This is strange, still I don't know why it will not work!

Now my jar size is 10KB & works good! :)

Comment: Thank you! This also solves my problem where a JAR written in Scala was uploaded to a Databricks cluster. I encountered the same error as yours.